# Bash script to wait for a process to finish on multiple servers

Tags: bash, ssh, process, wait

I wanted to ssh to multiple servers remotely and check whether any processes running on those servers and wait until the process to get finished. I have written the below code but this checks only for the first ip in the file(ip.txt) since I added 'continue' statement. I need to modify this code.

```
  while read IP
  do
    ssh ubuntu@$IP "pgrep -f pattern"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "Process is running" 
       sleep 10
       continue
    else
       echo "Process is not running"
    fi
  done < ip.txt
```

Comment: you'll need to stop `ssh` from eating standard input with `-n` or by closing stdin

Comment: Actually I tried with -n option. The problem is not with ssh. It is running in loop to check whether process is running on first ip only. Here is the output:                   
     12684
     13445
     Process is running for XXXXXX
     12684
     13445
     Process is running for XXXXXX
    12684
    13445
    Process is running for XXXXXX
    12684
    13445

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to get your list of IPs sorted first, and then iterate over it:

```
mapfile ipaddresses < ip.txt
canary=alive
while [[ "alive" == "$canary" ]]; do
  canary=dead
  for ip in ${ipaddresses[@]}; do
    if ssh ubuntu@$ip "pgrep -f pattern"; then
      echo "Process is running on $ip"
      canary=alive
      sleep 10
      continue
    else
      echo "Process not running on $ip"
    fi
  done
done
```

If you are still stuck on a version of `bash` below 4, replace the `mapfile` command with:

```
read -r ipaddresses <<< "$( cat ip.txt )"
```

Comment: I have three server ip's in ip.txt. It printed the process running on three different ip's and exited.                                                                                    12684
13445
23203
23334
Process is running on X.X.X.44
18048
18335
Process is running on X.X.X.55
29101
29972
Process is running on X.X.X.101

Comment: I've fixed the error; it will now run until it does not see any servers with your process running.

Comment: Does it checks parallely for all the three servers? does it sleeps for 10 seconds for one server at a time? I wanted to have the first option.

Comment: It does what your original does - checks each host in series; for any which do not have the process running it just goes to the next host.  If a host has the process running, it resets the canary,  pauses for ten seconds, and aborts out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues with the basic program flow here. Where you have one construct here, there are really a couple of things being tracked:

1. If any hosts in your list still have a running process on this check, we should record that and check again
2. If the number of hosts that still have a process is 0, we should exit.

So I would use two loops for this script. Also, `continue` shouldn't be needed here, and that's probably what is causing it to repeat the first host each time.

I did a few things differently, mainly testing on the number of PIDs returned from `psget` instead of checking the ssh exit code, and using some slightly different syntax. Here's the example I came up with that seems to work for what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

# get number of IPs from lines in file
NUM_IPS=$( cat ip.txt | wc -l )
echo "checking ${NUM_IPS} hosts..."

# Set number of running hosts to the max.  While arbitrary, it will 
# update to the correct number before reporting, and if it is 0 the
# while loop will exit immediately.
IPS_STILL_RUNNING=${NUM_IPS}

while [ "${IPS_STILL_RUNNING}" -gt "0" ]
do
    RUNNING_NOW=0
    for IP in $( cat ip.txt )
    do
        PROC_NUM=$( ssh ${IP} -- pgrep -f pattern | wc -l )
        if [ "${PROC_NUM}" -gt "0" ]; then
            echo "  ${IP}: still running"
            RUNNING_NOW=$(( RUNNING_NOW + 1 ))
        else
            echo "  ${IP}: not running"
        fi
    done
    echo "still running on $RUNNING_NOW hosts"
    IPS_STILL_RUNNING=${RUNNING_NOW}
    sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `ssh` to multiple hosts in parallel, use a program like `pdsh` (Parallel Distributed Shell).

For example, if your `ip.txt` contains IP addresses instead of hostnames, or a mix of hostnames & IP addresses:

```
hosts="$(awk '{l = l","$0}; END {sub(/^,/,"",l); print l}' ip.txt)"
while pdsh -l ubuntu -w "$hosts" 'pgrep -f pattern' 2>/dev/null | 
        grep pattern ; do
  sleep 10
done
```

This uses `awk` to build a comma-separated list of IP addresses to connect to with `ssh`.

If `ip.txt` file contains **only** hostnames instead of IP addresses, it's a lot simpler:

```
while pdsh -l ubuntu -F ./ip.txt -a 'pgrep -f pattern' 2>/dev/null | 
        grep pattern ; do
  sleep 10
done
```

Both of these assumes that `ip.txt` has one IP address or hostname per line.

The `while` loop runs until **none** of the hosts produce **any** output that matches the pattern.  stderr from the `pdsh` command is redirected to /dev/null to avoid spamming the terminal with error messages when the `pgrep` command returns exit code 1 to `pdsh`.

The only output is from the `grep pattern` in the pipeline.  Use `grep -q pattern` if you want this silenced too.